# Regex: ignoring match with two brackets

Tags: php, regex, markdown, markup

I try to match markup by regex:

```
1. thats an [www.external.com External Link], as you can see
2. thats an [[Internal Link]], as you can see
```

That should result in

```
1. thats an [External Link](www.external.com), as you can see
2. thats an [Internal Link](wiki.com/Internal Link), as you can see
```

Both of it work fine with this preg_replaces:

```
1. $line = preg_replace("/(\[)(.*?)( )(.*)(\])/", "[$4]($2)", $line);            
2. $line = preg_replace("/(\[\[)(.*)(\]\])/",   "[$2](wiki.com/$2)", $line);
```

But they interfere with each other, so using the replaces one after the other returns ugly results. So Iam trying to ignore in one of the matches the other one. I tried to replace the first regex by this one:

```
([^\[]{0,})(\[)([^\[]{1,})( )(.*)(])
```

It should check if there is only one `[` and the char after and before isn't a `[`. But its still matching the `[Internal Link]` within the `[]`, but it should ignore this part completely

Comment: Do it in one pass with `preg_replace_callback`. Or more simple, find an already made parser.

Comment: I don't understand, how it could work with callback? because I want the pattern to be ignored, not to be further processed. And yes I would like to find a markup->markdown lib, but couldn't find any yet. And actually its not such a lot magic I need, I already did the most by myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `preg_replace_callback` you can build a pattern to handle the two cases and to define a conditional replacement in the callback function. In this way the string is parsed only once.

```
$str =  <<<'EOD'
1. thats an [www.external.com External Link], as you can see
2. thats an [[Internal Link]], as you can see
EOD;

$domain = 'wiki.com';
$pattern = '~\[(?:\[([^]]+)]|([^] ]+) ([^]]+))]~';    

$str = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function ($m) use ($domain) {
    return empty($m[1]) ? "[$m[3]]($m[2])" : "[$m[1]]($domain/$m[1])";
}, $str);

echo $str;
```

The pattern uses an alternation `(?: xxx | yyy)`. The first branch describes internal links and the second external links.

When the second branch succeeds the first capture group 1 is empty (but defined). The callback function has to test it to know which branch succeeds and to return the appropriate replacement string.

Comment: thyx, works like charme.You just have to interchange the keys [$m[2]]($m[3]) = [$m[3]]($m[2]).